# How do I run Python scripts automatically on Jetson TX2?

Tags: python, nvidia-jetson

I tried `crontab -e`.

@reboot python3 /home/hyebin/project/tensorrt_demos/trt_ssd.py --model ssd_mobilenet_v2_face --usb --vid 1 --width 1280 --height 780

1.Do I just have to add it to the bottom line of the `crontab -e`?
2. Is it okay to have additions, such as '--model'?
3. What should I do if we have such additions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's better to use absolute paths in crontab rather that just `python3`.

example:
`@reboot  /path/to/command arg1 arg2`

it should work fine with arguments such as `--model`

to find your absolute path to python3 you can run `which python3` and use that

Comment: python3's absolute paths is /usr/bin/python3      So I use '@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/hyebin/project/tensorrt_demos/trt_ssd.py --model ssd_mobilenet_v2 --usb --vid 0 --width 1280 --height 720' Is it right?